# Yeoman Angularjs Generator issue-Mac

Tags: angularjs, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I've seen other similar Yeoman issues regarding the angular generator, but none addressing this particular error. The `yo doctor` command tells me everything is good and then when I try to run `$ npm install -g generator-angular`I get the following message. I'm not sure if its a permissions problem or what. I would be grateful for any help.

```
Christophers-MacBook-Pro% npm install -g generator-angular
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "generator-angular"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/christopherfristoe
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular'
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular'
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator- angular']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular' }
npm ERR! not ok code 0
Christophers-MacBook-Pro%
```

Comment: try ``sudo pm install -g generator-angular``

Comment: Yes and all I got was: 

`Christophers-MacBook-Pro% sudo pm install -g generator-angular
sudo: pm: command not found
Christophers-MacBook-Pro%`

Comment: Aditya's post missed the "n" in npm: try sudo npm install -g generator-angular

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. `yo -h`tells me that angular is installed. When I run it it drops a the separate package into my /Users directory:
`Gruntfile.js bower.json package.json
app  node_modules test`

No matter where I run yo it drops these packages in the /User directory. I'll keep digging, but again, thanks for helping me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Your user does not have proper access to the /usr/local/lib/node_modules directory. This is where npm is trying to place the libraries.

Run the following command with your username inserted in place of 'username':

sudo chown -R 'username' /usr/local/lib/node_modules

and then re-run your original command.